# How do i use pagination in django

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

The code is not clear, Want to use pagination in django template.

What does in views.py ??
what does in settings,py ??

Template is:-

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
                <div class="main_content">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                      <h3 class="heading">Application View</h3>
                        <div class="row-fluid">

                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mediaTable">
                                <thead><tr><th>App Id</th><th>Job Title</th><th>oDesk Id</th><th>Client Spent</th><th>Job Type</th><th>Notes</th><th colspan=2>Action</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for i in getvalue %}
 <tr>

<td>{{ i.app_id }}</td>
<td>{{ i.job_title }}</td>
<td>{{ i.odesk_id }}</td>
<td>{{ i.client_spent }}</td>
<td>{{ i.job_type }}</td>
<td>{{ i.notes_type }}</td>
<td><a href="/interview/?id={{i.app_id}}&oid={{i.odesk_id}}" title="Interview"><i class="splashy-document_letter_okay"></i></a></td>

<td><a href="/del/?id={{i.app_id}}" title="Remove"><i class="splashy-document_letter_remove"></i></a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django's default paging option
look...,

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

Get pagination up and running in less than 5 minutes using django-endless-pagination:

http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
pip install django-endless-pagination
```

Add `endless-pagination` in your Installed apps.

Finally, on your template do like this:

```
{% load endless %}

{% paginate entries %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {# your code to show the entry #}
{% endfor %}
{% show_pages %}
```